# What is the meaning of whatever is written in this taweez i dont believe in these and i am aware that these are haram but baba met a man who gave him

Tags: sunni, shirk

Some man gave this taweez to my baba saying that our house have some jinns in it i know this is haram and i am not happy about it embarrassed aswell but what should i do please explain what this means whatever that is written on it and what should i do he wanted baba to paste it over the bathroom door [image] i want explaination of it so that i could tell my baba and mama that we should not believe it and throw it away this can never do anything. Allah alone has the power over everything beshk.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that you would need to know that Allah is the most greatest, and has power over all things. And the only way to remove jinns is to ask Allah to protect you. The paper itself should not believe in and should he token to a imam. There is a possibility that the paper could be black magic. Please take it to a shaikh, and not random strangers online.